# What does this apparmor message mean?

Tags: ubuntu, apparmor

Here goes the message logged in `/var/log/kern.log`.

> `Apr 30 00:01:01 home kernel: [ 7796.631540] audit: type=1400 audit(1588201261.517:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/lsp.exclude" pid=10064 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=125 ouid=0`

Due to this, I can't start the `mysql` server.

I tried to include `mysqld` in `/etc/lsp.exclude` but it didn't help.

Any suggestions? I am using Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

The command `mysqld` is restricted by the AppArmor profile `/usr/sbin/mysqld` and has tried opening the file `/etc/lsp.exclude` for reading but the profile does not allow that.

So you have to extend that profile by this permission (and restart AppArmor). Or you change the MySQL config so that it does not try to open this file any more.

Answer (score 0):

That line means that a read attempt to `/etc/lsp.exclude` was made by `/usr/sbin/mysqld` and it was denied by the kernel, which you correctly diagnosed.

It's a bit of mystery to me what that file is doing and why mysql needs it. To add it to the profile, `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, add the line:

```
/etc/lsp.exclude r,
```

Then restart the apparmor service to reload the profile you just created. After that, MySQL may have better luck.